# Add new tag to the XML using Batch script

Tags: xml

I am trying to add a new XML tag `ClaimAdminClaimNum>000114700002</ClaimAdminClaimNum>` after the existing tag 
`<MPN_OPT_OUT_TERM_DATE/>` in the below XML code.

Where the new value 000114700002 in the new ClaimAdminClaimNum tag should be the same value as in the another existing tag 
`<CLAIM_NUM>0001147-00002</CLAIM_NUM>` but without the hyphen.

Please refer to the below code and please advise your suggestions.

Current XML code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 -<dataroot>
  -<Standard_x0020_Claim>

   <CLAIM_LOAD_TYPE_INDICATOR>U</CLAIM_LOAD_TYPE_INDICATOR>
   <PATIENT_LOAD_TYPE_INDICATOR>U</PATIENT_LOAD_TYPE_INDICATOR>
   <PATIENT_ID_NUM>431586385</PATIENT_ID_NUM>
   <LAST_NAME>BACON</LAST_NAME>
   <CLAIM_NUM>0001147-00002</CLAIM_NUM>
   <PATIENT_NOTES_LENGTH/>
   <JURIS_CLAIM_NUMBER/>
   <MPN_OPT_OUT_EFF_DATE/>
   <MPN_OPT_OUT_TERM_DATE/>

  </Standard_x0020_Claim>"
```

Expected XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<dataroot>
-<Standard_x0020_Claim>

  <CLAIM_LOAD_TYPE_INDICATOR>U</CLAIM_LOAD_TYPE_INDICATOR>
  <PATIENT_LOAD_TYPE_INDICATOR>U</PATIENT_LOAD_TYPE_INDICATOR>
  <PATIENT_ID_NUM>431586385</PATIENT_ID_NUM>
  <LAST_NAME>BACON</LAST_NAME>
  <CLAIM_NUM>0001147-00002</CLAIM_NUM>
  <PATIENT_NOTES_LENGTH/>
  <JURIS_CLAIM_NUMBER/>
  <MPN_OPT_OUT_EFF_DATE/>
  <MPN_OPT_OUT_TERM_DATE/>
  <ClaimAdminClaimNum>000114700002</ClaimAdminClaimNum>

 </Standard_x0020_Claim>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an XML-aware tool to modify XML. For example, in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), you can write:

```
open file.xml ;
my $claim_num = xsh:subst(/dataroot/Standard_x0020_Claim/CLAIM_NUM, '-', '') ;
my $new := insert element ClaimAdminClaimNum
                  after /dataroot/Standard_x0020_Claim/MPN_OPT_OUT_TERM_DATE ;
set $new/text() $claim_num ;

save :b ;
```

Comment: Hello Sir, Thank you so much for your reply. I don't know how to code in XSH, exploring in google to find the software to install and edit the XML. Besides, there are multiple claims in the same XML file which has to undergo this change and there are almost 150 XML files i have to modify with this expected output. Can this looping be done using XSH? If this can also be achieved using Batch script, please propose a solution on BAT script

Comment: As you can find in the link I provided, `xsh` can loop both over elements and files.

Comment: Excellent! I will install that editing software and try your code and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: If possible, any one please advise an alternate solution on BAT script too.

Comment: Hello Sir, i don't have any rights to install any software on my client computer and my client is also not encouraging on that. Is there a solution available in BAT script? Please help.